# Validate to app store. Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. iCloud

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, icloud, code-signing

I'm receiving this error in the validate process in Xcode and is driving me crazy. I spent several hours trying to fix it but I can't find the solution.

We have the correct distribution certificate, provisioning profile and everything I can imagine related to this. I already revoke and rebuild all my project but I still got the same error.

My last solution was to disable iCloud and upload the app (no errors and right now is on review) to be on time but I need to upload a first update with iCloud included soon.

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNtQw.png)

Comment: Did you enable your iCloud service when you create your app id from developer site?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/992625#992625

Basically you shouldn't use iCloud containers yet, since it's an iOS8 feature. Took me a while to figure that out as well....

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same exact error.  I appreciate your post because the only solution I've found is what you suggested - disable iCloud on the App ID in developer.apple.com.  If you go in to edit the App ID settings, you'll see "iCloud (Beta)."  This makes me wonder if Apple has (presumably mistakenly) tied all iCloud usage to the new APIs (e.g. CloudKit), which of course cannot be submitted to the App Store until iOS 8.  Beyond waiting for iOS 8, contacting Apple or playing with the entitlements file (and then re-signing) might be our only options.

Comment: I do not think it was a mistake. I think it was intentional. That functionality is in beta. They may need to change the APIs and/or reset/delete anything saved on iCloud with that API at any time. Users should not have an app with that functionality enabled before it's out of beta.

Comment: @AnalogFile Totally agree with all of that.  What I'm seeing in the developer portal is iCloud (as a whole) is beta.  What if you have pre-iOS8 iCloud functionality and want to release an update?  Even with the beta _components_ unchecked, I'm unsure of how one would do that right now because if I have iCloud in my entitlements at all it fails validation.

Comment: Did you try using XCode 5? Because, you know, XCode 6 is in beta too.